# Precalc trouble finding polynomial with rational coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I recently absolutely bombed my precalculus mid-term, and I'm reeling from that at the moment. I'm trying to find out where I went wrong.

One of the ones I'm continuing to have problems with says (and I've changed the numbers here, so I'm not posting any kind test material): find a polynomial function of lowest degree with rational coefficients and some of its zeroes at $0$, $-\sqrt{3}$, and $1+i$.

So, the first thing I did was say:
$$f(x) = x(x+\sqrt{3})(x-(1-i))(x-(1+i))$$

Then... I kind of lost the plot. I multiplied everything out, hoping to reduce to a single polynomial, but what I ended with (twice) wasn't an answer choice.

so, starting with the two right side parens (excuse the crappy ASCII table):
$$(x-1+i)(x-1-i)$$

```
    x  -1   +i  
  ------------  
x | x2 -x  +xi
  |
-1|-x  +1  -i 
  |
-i|-xi +i  +1
```

...which got me a total of $x^2-2x+2$

Plugging that back into the original:
$$f(x) = x(x+\sqrt{3})(x^2-2x+2)$$

Then taking the easy route and multiplying the sigleton $x$:
$$f(x) = (x+\sqrt{3})(x^3-2x^2+2x)$$

...and then another crappy ASCII table:

```
       x    +√3
     ------------  
  x3 | x4   +√3x3
     |
-2x2 |-2x3 -2√3x2 
     |
 +2x |+2x2 +2√3x
```

...which equals:
$$f(x) = x^4-2x^3+\sqrt{3}x^3-\sqrt{3}x^2+2\sqrt{3}x$$

which I suppose could be written:
$$f(x) = x^4 + (-2+\sqrt{3})x^3-\sqrt{3}x^2+2\sqrt{3}x$$

...and none of the answers was even close to this.

Where did I go wrong? Am I approaching this problem the wrong way, somehow?

The answer I ended up going with (which was marked wrong) looked like the original problem I set up:
$$f(x) = x(x+\sqrt{3})(x-(1-i))(x-(1+i))$$

Please hellllllp!

---

**EDIT**
D'oh. I left out the $+\sqrt{3}$... so, putting that back in there:

```
     x   +√3
   ----------
 x |  x2 +√3x
-√3|-√3x  -3
```

so:
$$f(x) = (x^2-3)(x^3-2x^2+2x)$$

$$f(x) = x^5-2x^4-x^3+6x^2-6x$$

**ARGH** Thank you so much @quasi !

Comment: Hint: Since the polynomial is required to have rational coefficients, if $-\sqrt{3}$ is a zero, then so is $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Oh wow. I wanted it to be something arcane and difficult (facepalm)